# DHCP-Options - NTP Settings

Tags: amazon-web-services

I see that we have **NTP servers** as an option when we create **DHCP-Options** in AWS VPC.

What i want to know is if we need to refer it to an internal NTP server(configured to point to eternal NTP Pool) or could we also refer to an External NTP pool?

-Pasha

Answer (score 2):

You need to point it at NTP server(s) to which you have a clear network path.  If your firewall settings allow you to speak UCP/123 to arbitrary external addresses, and hear the replies, then putting external servers is fine.

That said, netiquette suggests that you shouldn't bind each and every one of your servers to external time sources; if you have any significant number of servers (say, more than five), it's better practice to nominate two or three of your servers as time sources, sync those to the external pool, and have all the rest of your internal servers sync to that internal group.

Comment: yea, i have a windows environment, so would adding a ntp server info in dhcp option in VPC help??

Comment: I don't know anything about Windows, sorry.